I need to use underline tool option for my ckeditor used in .net mvc project
I used this ckeditor cdn
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/39.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
When I use this code in js for ckeditor creation with toolbar options, I get all the options listed but not underline tool.
    ClassicEditor.create(this, {
        toolbar: ['bold', 'italic', 'Underline', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'link'],
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });

And I get this error in console when loaded:
 toolbarview-item-unavailable Objectitem: "Underline"[[Prototype]]: Object 
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html#error-toolbarview-item-unavailable

I need to use underline tool in my editor

There are some errors in your attempt as UI elements are mixed case so some need to be Underline and others underline
To add Underline

It needs to be defined Underline in the imports
<script type="module">
            import {
                ClassicEditor,
                Essentials,
                Bold,
                Italic,
                Font,
                Underline,
                Paragraph
            } from 'ckeditor5';

and for plugins but lowercase for the toolbar
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
                    plugins: [ Essentials, Bold, Italic, Font, Paragraph, Underline, ],
                    toolbar: [
                        'undo', 'redo', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', '|',
                        'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor'
                    ]
 

Test it out in this snippet


<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>CKEditor 5 - Quick start CDN</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/43.3.1/ckeditor5.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="editor">
            <p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>
        </div>

        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "ckeditor5": "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/43.3.1/ckeditor5.js",
                    "ckeditor5/": "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/43.3.1/"
                }
            }
        </script>

        <script type="module">
            import {
                ClassicEditor,
                Essentials,
                Bold,
                Italic,
                Font,
                Underline,
                Paragraph
            } from 'ckeditor5';

            ClassicEditor
                .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
                    plugins: [ Essentials, Bold, Italic, Font, Paragraph, Underline, ],
                    toolbar: [
                        'undo', 'redo', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', '|',
                        'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor'
                    ]
                } )
                .then( /* ... */ )
                .catch( /* ... */ );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>



